# How to get object in ObjectSet by ID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-web-api

Sorry for n00b question, documentation not as easy to find as something like Django's QuerySet.

I'm trying to do something super simple like

```
context.Object.get(id)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler method is to use `FirstOrDefault` which takes a filter, just like `Where()`. Something like this:

```
var product = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a Product entity type with primary key of Id, and the container set is Products, then

`var product = context.Products.where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();`